# Trisurf for App Designer implemented figure.

Tags: matlab-app-designer

I try to use the standard trisurf() function in Matlab App Designer in an uifigure, more precisely in the so called axes object.

For example for the surf() function I can use surf(app.View, my_Data) and it will plot it in the app.View object (which is a figure implemented in the GUI). However, this does not work for trisurf. Something like trisurf(app.View, my_Data) leads to an error.

Could someone explain how it works? Thanks a lot.

Thanks, Best J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRISURF doesn't appear to support an axes to be passed in as the first input argument. Instead, it can take it via PV pairs as follows:

```
trisurf(my_Data, 'Parent', app.View)
```